# Howto upload a video preview to the appstore

Tags: video, app-store-connect

Again, only problems with this Apple stuff, but sadly I have to work with.

I simply want to upload a video preview for my app in app store.
I am pretty sure, I am doing it correct.

I meet all the specifications, otherwise I get a meaningfull error message saying the movie is too long or video format is not correct.

Now I am able to add the video to the preview part. I can see the video as one picture and there is a white circle in it. But when saving, it simply says, there is no change and my video is not uploaded. After 5 tries I got a message the file could not be uploaded.

Then I tried to upload the video from a windows browser (I normally do the most possible on windows, because there it works), but as expected it says it can only be uploaded from a safary browser. How stupid is this again. Then downloaded the safary browser on windows and tried again. With the safari browser on windows I even can't display the "Itunes Connect" page correctly. embarrassing , embarrassing.

Does anyone else has this problem ? Does anyone has a hint ?
How can I upload the video, which is correct ?

Comment: Please try to clarify the issue at hand instead of bashing Apple products.

Answer (score 4):

[Apple doesn't appear to allow for uploads of app previews from Windows computers: their page states that uploads must be done from Safari and 10.10 (though I suspect 10.11 would work as well.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10) Note again the very specific requirements, and please, triple check you meet all of them when uploading from a Mac.